# BigDecimal после десериализации приобретает экспоненциальный вид

Tags: java, serializable, bigdecimal

Расчитываются цены типа BigDecimal. Они сериализуются. Файл передается другому приложению. После десериализации, значения с нулями, например 30, 600 приобретают вид 3E+1, 6E+2. Можно ли указать сериализатору какой-то флаг, чтобы это преобразование не просиходило?

Comment: Код сериализации в студию

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод `toPlainString()` вместо `toString()`.

**Например**

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("4930592405923095023950238502395.3259023950235902");
System.out.println(b.toPlainString());

Output: 4930592405923095023950238502395.3259023950235902
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834879/format-bigdecimal-without-scientific-notation-with-full-precission/15834982#15834982).

Comment: Да, видел, спасибо. Ответ не подходит, поскольку интересует именно сериализация. Нужно сериализовать так, чтобы при десериализации уже был вид без экспонент. Код десериализации трогать не могу

Comment: Ну, это же объект BigDecimal, который хранит в своих параметрах значение. Это не число или строка. А тот или иной формат представления у нас появляется, когда мы приводим этот объект к строке. И вот тут уже можно сказать объекту, каким способом ему надо преобразовываться в строку.

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov с точки зрения сериализации бессмысленно делать разницу между 1E+4 и 10000. У вас вопрос, связанный с представлением, который лишь ловит сайд-эффекты от сериализации (чего конечно не должно быть, но так уже случилось), и его бесполезно лечить какой-то другой сериализацией